# Evaluate the improper integral: $\int _0^{+\infty }\:\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+9\right)\cdot \sqrt[3]{x^2+9}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int _0^{+\infty }\:\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+9\right)\cdot \sqrt[3]{x^2+9}}$$
Wolfram says strange things. And you need to solve analytically. Help.

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{2\times3^{2/3} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}$ is ok, not so strange :-)

Comment: I do not understand it))

Comment: which part don't you understand? $\Gamma$ is a function, look here for details, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of solution you need? There's no elementary anti-derivative

Comment: @Dylan $x \to \tan x$ should do the job. See the solution by Jack D'Aurizio below ...

Comment: @Math-fun If it wasn't clear, the question was directed at the OP. I know the method, but the Beta function is definitely not elementary.

Comment: @Dylan I see; OP had problems understanding Gamma function, it seems ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}(x^2+9)^{-4/3}\,dx = 3^{-5/3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+z^2)^{-4/3}\,dz=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{2\cdot 3^{5/3}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}\end{align*}$$
by using the substitution $z=\tan\theta$ and Euler's [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). That simplifies to:
$$ I =\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{3^{2/3}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}. $$

Comment: Oh my God. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

$$x=3\sinh(t)$$

yields

$$
\frac{1}{3 \cdot3^{2/3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\cosh^{4/3}(t)}=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{2 \cdot3^{2/3} \sqrt{\pi }}
$$